# Checking for Last Node

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml. How do I test for last node?

```
<PatientDetailsXML>             
 <PList> 
               <PName type="Patient">
            <properties>
                <Room bedType="Auto" />
                <PName title="Joe Beom" PId="1234">
                    <Details>
                        <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Wallet" />
                        <classification classification="Humor" category="None" />
                        <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                    </Details>
                </PName>
                </properties>
            <childEvents>
            </childEvents>
        </PName>
                <PName type="Patient">
            <properties>
                <Room bedType="Auto" />
                <PName title="John Bair" PId="1234">
                    <Details>
                        <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Found" />
                        <classification classification="Humor" category="None" />
                        <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                    </Details>
                </PName>
                </properties>
            <childEvents>
            </childEvents>
        </PName>
<!-- End of List -->
</PList>
</PatientDetailsXML>
```

During the for loop I end up `<!-- End of List -->`, I do a test for the comment but then I need to also test if there is no node after that.

```
var nodes = docs.SelectNodes(query).OfType<XmlNode>().ToArray();
XmlNodeList nodeList = docs.SelectNodes(query);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count(); i++)
{
  XmlNode multinextnode = nodes[i];

if (multinextnodetest == "#comment")
{
  multinextnode.NextSibling; 
    {
      if (multinextnode.Equals(multinextnode.LastChild))
      {
        Console.WriteLine("final");
      }
       // some code 

    }
 }
        // somecode
  }
```

This `multinextnode.Equals(multinextnode.LastChild)` doesn't seem to work for me. In the for loop I'm jumping to next node as you can see above `multinextnode.NextSibling`. This is absolutely necessary to achieve my target with the code. But during the jump I may hit a `null` in the `multinextnode`. Which means there is no child/sibling/node after that, right before `</PList>`. So I need to do a test for lastchild

Right now I'm simply doing a null test and getting the job done. But I need to know if there is a better way.

Comment: We need to see a little more code than that.  Where is this `for` loop you mention?  What is the definition of `multinextnode` and `multinextnodetest`?   Ideally, you should include a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Comment: Why do you relay on comment? If someone remove/modify this comment, your XML will become invalid?

Comment: it picks it up as node. So then I have to test if its a comment I ignore it. SO the comment happens to be picked up as the last node.

Comment: The code is quite huge so I happen to include only the code I was testing for the last child.

Comment: @user726720, so, if someone will remove/modify this comment, your code will not work at all?

Comment: what is definition of "multinextnode" ?

Comment: I have updated my question with more code please check.

Comment: Why don't you just use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)? `var lastPNameNode = docs.SelectSingleNode("/PatientDetailsXML/PList/PName[last()]");`

Comment: I'm pretty sure XML does not allow comments. We have no idea why you would want to use comments in XML. My suggestion would be to treat the comment as a string wrapped in a tag.